# How can I represent time of the day in Java?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I want to be able to create a calendar of sorts, where each day is composed of time slots. What is the best way to represent this setup in Java? I am parsing the information and I get it as *10:00* and an int *3* where the int represents the hours the event will take.

I want to be able to add events easily, they will never really be deleted, but they will often be looked up.

I took a look at the Java.text.DateFormat in hopes that it could handle my needs but it seems it is mostly for printing the output.

Comment: I would probably use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Comment: So, create a `CalendarEvent` class which holds a `startTime` and an `eventLength`. I agree with others that Joda-Time will be a useful library for storing your dates/times/etc. and doing calculations on them.

Comment: You could represent the time value using SimpleDateFormat, remember, Date/DateTime is divorced from the format, so it won't carry the for at with it. You could use Calendar to calculate the future time based on the pivot Date, but I'd personally use Joda-Time as it generally simplifies the overall process of performing calculations on dates/ time values. Remember, you'll want more then just time, as it would be possible for an event to expand beyond the boundaries of current day ;)

Comment: @user1198778 Title on this question is poor, misleading.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (or wait for the Java 8 where it's successor is implemented).
This lib contains powerful parsing options and handy manipulation options as well. If you receive an int with hours the event will take, you can use it to i.e. get the end time.

```
int hours = (parsed from input);
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");     
LocalTime startTime = dtf.parseLocalTime(stringWithTimeFromUser);
LocalTime endTime = startTime.plusHours(hours);
```

If you need to convert it to a datetime you can combine the classes as well. I.e. if you have the datetime and just want to change the time to what user has provided, you would:

```
DateTime dateTime = getItFromSomewhere();
DateTime dateTimeWithNewTime = dateTime.withFields(localTime);
```

Typically you would get the date from the users as well though ;)

The library has extensive documention, look there.

Comment: I'm curious what would happen with LocalTime if you added enough time to push it over the current day (ie set to 10pm and the add 4 hours) would you be able to detect this change (without having to restore to before/after comparison)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer What happens when you add 4 hours to 10 PM? The hands on the clock keep on spinning around the dial. `System.out.println( new LocalTime( 22, 0 ).plusHours( 4 ) );` yields `02:00:00.000`. Nothing to detect really, otherwise you'd be using a DateTime.

Comment: @BasilBourque lol ;).  What I'm curious about is how could you detect that without a `Date` component, for example, if I wanted to calculate the "split" between the two (ie render 2200-2400 on one column and 0000-0200 on the next), would it be possible to know that I've skipped a date boundary using `LocalTime`? This is not a criticism, just curiosity.  I've use `LocalTime` before to calculate the time difference which was awesome

Comment: Looked at class doc, didn't see anything relevant other than maybe a constant for MIDNIGHT. My thinking is… the "split" you refer to is actually *the meaning of a date*. If the result of addition is a different day-of-month, then you know you rolled over. I think of `LocalTime` as one of those toy clocks with big chunky minute and hour hands on a dial, meant to be moved around and around manually for a little kid learning to tell time. I mean that `LocalTime` is a pretend time-of-day going round-and-round endlessly with no point to it. If you care about rolling over, then you care about dates.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Assuming you are not adding more than 24 hours (which you could easily check for) you could check if `newLocalTime.isBefore(previousLocalTime)` ;)
Since you would have to check if you're not adding more than 24 hours, you could also get how much time you've got left till midnight and verify against that: `Minutes.minutesBetween(previousLocalTime, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT).getMinutes()`

I hope everyone here realises though that all this makes little sense - if you need to check this you need a DateTime :)

Answer (score 2):

Use Joda-Time to represent the actual time.  Then I'd use PrimeFaces Schedule component (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/scheduleHome.jsf) for display.

This would mean learning JSF & JPA libraries.

Comment: Nitpick: I don't think there's enough context to know how the OP intends to represent this concept to a user, but that's just me ;)

Comment: He says "create a calendar of sorts, where each day is composed of time slots".

Comment: Yep, but that doesn't dictate the framework, could do this using Swing or JavaFX for example

Answer (score 2):

## No To Old Bundled Classes

Avoid the bundled java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar, and java.text.DateFormat/SimpleDateFormat classes. They are notoriously troublesome.

## Yes to Joda-Time

Yes, Joda-Time 2.3 has classes for your needs.

DateTime represents a moment. See [`Period`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html), [`Duration`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html), and [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) classes that  all relate to spans of time.

### DateTime Class

A [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) represents a moment in time along with a time zone. Unlike a java.util.Date that *seems* to have a time zone but truly does not, a DateTime really does have a time zone assigned. Almost always best to specify the time zone, otherwise you get the JVM's default time zone.

### Period Class

The [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines a textual way to to represent a span of time, called a [Duration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). Uses this format: `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. To be more flexible, rather than store an int of 3 for three hours, you might store `PT3H` where "P" means Period, "T" means Time-portion, and "3H" means three hours. In Joda-Time, the [`Period`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) class takes that string as a constructor and outputs it when calling [`toString`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractPeriod.html#toString%28%29). So one way to do your calendar is store a DateTime (start) and a ISO string "Duration".

```java
Period period = new Period( "PT3H" );
```

### Duration Class

An alternative common way is to store a duration in milliseconds. This is basically what the [`Duration`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) field in Joda-Time does, wraps a milliseconds count.

### Interval Class

In [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) in Joda-Time represents span with a specific DateTime start and a DateTime end. You may not want to store that, but instantiating such objects may have other uses. This class offers handy methods such as "overlap" and [`containsNow`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInterval.html#containsNow%28%29). If "containsNow" returns true, you know that event in question is now happening.

```java
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime( 2014, 1, 23, 14, 0, 0, timeZone );
Interval interval = new Interval( startDateTime, period );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "interval: " + interval );
```

When run…

```
interval: 2014-01-23T14:00:00.000+01:00/2014-01-23T17:00:00.000+01:00
```

## Yes to java.time.*

[Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) brings a new [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) of classes defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). These classes were inspired by Joda-Time but are entirely re-architected.

You can use Joda-Time today and continue in Java 8, as the project continues to be maintained actively. Later you learn to transition to the java.time package.